# How to calculate crc for byte array?

Tags: c, embedded, crc

I understand how CRC for a byte can be calculated by modulo 2 division with a polynomial but I don't understand how do you calculate CRC for data consisting of byte arrays. CRC for a single byte can be calculated by this following code

```
#define WIDTH  8
#define TOPBIT 1 << 7
#define POLYNOMIAL 0xD8

uint8_t(uint8_t const message)
{
    uint8_t remainder = 0;  
    remainder ^= message;
    for (uint8_t bit = 8; bit > 0; --bit)
    {
        if (remainder & TOPBIT)
        {
            remainder = (remainder << 1) ^ POLYNOMIAL;
        }
        else
        {
            remainder = (remainder << 1);
        }
    }
    return (remainder);

}
```

but what about byte array ? I found above code on [this site](https://barrgroup.com/Embedded-Systems/How-To/CRC-Calculation-C-Code), Author also gave the code for byte array where he just XOR'ed current remainder with next byte

```
remainder ^= (message[byte] << (WIDTH - 8));
```

I don't quite understand why? why he XOR'ed to get in the next byte into remainder?

Comment: Not clear what your problem is. We are not to explain CRC calculation,that is too broad. There are a lot of resources about CRCs to be found. Start with Wikipedia and dig further.

Comment: @Olaf care to explain?

Comment: Wikipedia has an extensive article on CRC and how to calculate them.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  I am not asking how to get CRC I understand that but I don't understand why author XORed remainder with next byte in case of byte array

Comment: CRC for a single byte is wholly unexciting.  It is only interesting when applied to multiple bytes in some shape or form.  There are rules for how to do the chaining.  IIRC, Wikipedia explains them.

Comment: @Sigma _'but I don't understand why author XORed remainder with next byte in case of byte array'_ Please. Compile it, debug it and think.

Comment: Tip: Use `()` with `TOPBIT (1 << 7)` to avoid unexpected code - although not an issue here.

Comment: "I don't quite understand why? why he XOR'ed to get in the next byte into remainder?" --> posting what you expected would help others explain the code to you.

Comment: http://www.sunshine2k.de/articles/coding/crc/understanding_crc.html

Comment: Read [this tutorial](http://www.ross.net/crc/download/crc_v3.txt). It will explain that and much more.

Comment: The missing parentheses in the `TOPBIT` define (as @chux wrote above) indicate that you changed the original code from the article. Do not do this if you don't understand what you're doing. Also, if you are not too tight with RAM, you might want to check the lookup table CRC version shown at the bottom of the article.

Answer (score 2):

See [A painless guide to CRC error detection algorithms](http://www.ross.net/crc/crcpaper.html). It has everything on CRCs, including your question. An array is treated as a single massive number so the remainder is carried over to the next byte. CRC is the remainder that is left over at the end.

Comment: @kiner_shah Alternatively get it [here](https://archive.org/stream/PainlessCRC/crc_v3.txt)

Answer (score 0):

Look at page on wikipedia [Mathematics of cyclic redundancy checks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics_of_cyclic_redundancy_checks) It turns out that CRC is a linear operation meaning that crc(x^y^z) = crc(x)crc(y)crc(x) and hence the author XOR'd the remainder of previous byte with the next byte